# Cant install mosquitto in aws linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

I am getting the following error while installing mosquitto in my aws instance can anyone help.

```
[root@ec2-user]# yum install mosquitto
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package mosquitto available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was resolved by installing the following first

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
```